# Gradles init --type java-library works in putty but comes up with error when executing same command from php script

Tags: php, shell, gradle

I'm currently trying to incorporate Gradle into a web based java IDE, so that a user could build their files.
I've tested the command to do it using Putty and it yielded the exact results I expected(creating a series of directories and sub directories).

```
$command = 'cd /home/neema/sites/javaIDE.local/branches/develop/javaIDE/app/java/User1/test1 2>&1';
$command2 = '/home/neema/sites/javaIDE.local/branches/develop/javaIDE/app/gradle/bin/gradle init --type java-library 2>&1';
```

However when i run the above commands in shell_exec in php(console.logging the response)i get this error.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not create service of type InitScriptHandler using BuildScopeServices.createInitScriptHandler().
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I ran the stacktrace and this is the result, http://pastebin.com/YaHyWNR6.

I can't for the life of me understand why it won't work.
I've given the folder 'test1' all permissions (777) and now I've resorted to help :)

Thanks in advance to anyone with insight.

Comment: Are you using the same privileges from the command line as you are in PHP? Usually when a directory cannot be created as indicated in your stack trace, there is a permissions problem.

Comment: I've solved it :)
Had to create a .gradle file in /var/www